# How to switch code on appengine-web.xml for development & production?

Tags: class, google-app-engine, maven, instance

For deploying my java module on Google Appengine I use to call using [maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#managing_and_running_a_project_with_the_app_engine_maven_plugin) as below:

**mvn appengine:update** to deploy for production and
**mvn appengine:devserver** to deploy for local development

Since I got problem with **B1** instance class on local development (my localhost fails on respond to [/_ah/start/](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_states) request) so I want to switch the instance class to **F1** which is in my case it work when deploying for local development.

My question is how to put the both of class in **appengine-web.xml** so I don't  need to change the code when I switch deploying between local development and production.

Here is the my code for both instance class and what to run on the deploying using maven.

run this code when deploy **for production** (call mvn appengine:update )

```
<instance-class>B1</instance-class>
<basic-scaling>
<max-instances>1</max-instances>
<idle-timeout>10m</idle-timeout>
</basic-scaling>
```

run this code when deploy **for local development** (call mvn appengine:devserver)

```
<instance-class>F1</instance-class>
<automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>1</min-idle-instances>
    <max-idle-instances>1</max-idle-instances>
    <min-pending-latency>automatic</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>30ms</max-pending-latency>
</automatic-scaling>
```

Comment: Have you since found a way to do this?